# Unity LookAtMouse function kills movement performance

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

```
private void LookAtMouse()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(mouseLook), out var raycastHit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        _direction = (raycastHit.point - transform.position).normalized;
        _direction.y = 0;
        transform.forward = _direction;
    }
}
```

whenever I call this function in update it kills my movement. If I don't run this function everything works perfectly. I have tried using transform.LookAt() I tried using transform.Translate() in movement, Rigidbody.MovePosition(), changing anything else doesn't help.

If I comment out the transform.forward = _direction; then everything works perfect. what is it about that that makes my movement run game breakingly slow

I have tried every possible thing I can find online to fix this and nothing has been helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as any physics is involved you do not want to set things via `Transform` as this breaks the physics and collision detection.

You should be using [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) in combination with [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) within [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerLoop.FixedUpdate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call it in FixedUpdate
generally, I use Update just for catching Key input because it may be called +1000 time if your device is powerful, in the other hand fixed update is better to do the physics .iv it a try and replay if it didn't help to think in other solution;

Comment: it is in FixedUpdate. that was my original thought so I moved it away from the Key Inputs but still nothing